# Блокировка нажатий клавиш на клавиатурево время выполнения программы

Tags: java, winapi, swing, gui

Нужно сделать так чтобы во время выполнения программы при  нажатии на определенные клавиши или их сочетания не происходило никаких действий. Например ALT+CTRL+DEL не сработало, или например при нажатии на кнопку windows не выводилось меню пуск. Это вообще можно реализовать на java? Если да, то как помогите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие вещи нельзя делать на уровне приложения в принципе.

Если это терминал самообслуживания или автоматизированное рабочее место, и нужно чтобы никто не баловался, то это решается политиками Windows.

Не могу представить других ситуаций (кроме вредоносного ПО), где бы это могло понадобиться.